# Keyboard dismiss immediately when focusing textInput for first time react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

When I set `cardStyleInterpolator` to `forFadeFromBottomAndroid` or `forVerticalIOS` for a `Stack.Screen`, keyboard immediately dismiss when focusing on *TextInput*. This not happen for other type.

This only happen for first focus on *TextInput*.

Here is what's happening:

[image: RN]

```
function RootStack() {
return (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="GROUPS" component={GroupsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="GROUP" component={GroupScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="CREATE_POST"
      component={CreatePostScreen}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="SELECT_POST_TYPE"
      component={AnonymousTypeScreen}
      options={{
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent", opacity: 1 },
        headerShown: false,
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS,
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
}
```

and screen component is just simple component:

```
return (
  <View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TInput />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I am also facing this ....

Comment: did you find solution for that ?

Comment: @TusharPandey No, I changed `CardStyleInterpolators` type for now.

Comment: I think this issue related to new-update in react-navigation dependency.

Comment: hey I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded dependencies for react-navigation ( native & stack ), because previouslly my code was working, so tried this and it worked.

[image]

Comment: I am using these version: `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",`

Comment: just try to downgrade and see, your issue stills occurs or not.